# stacked difference bar chart in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to get a stacked bar bar plot of with the difference of the AUC of Test A and B

The plot should look similar to this one:
[image]

**Sample data:**

```
  df <- data.frame(test=rep(c("testA","testB"),2), AUC=c(0.8,0.9,0.6,0.3), reader=rep(c("reader1","reader2"),each=2))
```

**What I tried**

I know how to calculate the difference and assign colors..

```
df %>% 
  spread(test,AUC) %>%
  group_by(reader) %>% 
  mutate(dif=testA-testB) %>%
  gather(key,value,testA:testB) %>% 
  mutate(color=case_when(is.negative(dif)~"green",TRUE~"red")) -> df
```

**Where I fail**

I do not exactly know how to get the stacked plot using ggplot2

Must be something like:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=reader,y=value, fill=color...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

This is your data frame from the question, I just created it differently and made a deliberate factor for the computation.

```
data.frame(
  test = factor(rep(c("testA", "testB"), 2), levels = c("testA", "testB")),
  AUC = c(0.8, 0.9, 0.6, 0.3),
  reader = rep(c("reader1", "reader2"), each = 2),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> xdf
```

Now, we:

- group by reader
- ensure we're arranging the tests properly
- compute the difference and preserve the `testA` AUC
- make it long vs wide
- assign the color via a label so we can use a scale to get the legend
- set the color factor levels so we can get them positioned right in `geom_col()`
- un-negate any negative diff values (so they can stack properly)
- plot by reader and value, filling by the color label aesthetic
- stack them and ensure `testA` is on the bottom
- Set Y limits to 0,1 and name the axis properly
- Set X axis aesthetics to match the picture you gave us
- Use a manual fill to get the RGB (just with colorbrewer colors)
- Use a nice theme (though I'm heavily biased abt that)

Which is done via:

```
group_by(xdf, reader) %>%
  arrange(test) %>%
  summarise(
    diff = diff(AUC),
    testA_auc = AUC[1]
  ) %>%
  gather(measure, value, -reader) %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(
    measure == "diff" & (sign(value) == -1) ~ "Decrease with Test B",
    measure == "diff" & (sign(value) > -1) ~ "Increase with Test B",
    measure == "testA_auc" ~ "Test A"
  )) %>%
  mutate(
    color = factor(
      x = color,
      levels = c("Test A", "Increase with Test B", "Decrease with Test B")
    )
  ) %>%
  mutate(value = abs(value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reader, value, fill = color)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Estimated AUC", limits = c(0, 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete("Reader", labels = c("1", "2")) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = NULL, 
    values = c(
      "Test A" = "#2166ac", 
      "Increase with Test B" = "#5aae61", 
      "Decrease with Test B" = "#b2182b"
    )
  ) +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum_rc(grid = "Y")
```

[image]